# Retrieve value of input stored within array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a page where users input quantities for items and various totals are calculated using information pertaining to said items.  I'm attempting to display aggregates of the items' totals and in order to properly obtain the values I need, I'm checking to make sure each element involved in the calculation has some kind of value before attempting to do anything.  However, when I attempt to check, an error is thrown saying that the method is undefined.

```
if(itemTotals[i].innerHTML != "" && itemMaps[i].innerHTML != "" && itemCogs[i].innerHTML != "" && itemQuantities[i].value != ""){
    //Increment totals
}
```

The `itemQuantities[i].value` part is what throws the error.  I've tried using `.val()` and `.attr("value")` but none of them work.  I merely get the message that whatever I tried isn't a function.  How can I retrieve each input field's value in this context?  Am I retrieving the input fields improperly?

The array is initialized as follows.

```
var itemQuantities = document.getElementsByClassName("inputQty");
```

The other arrays involved in calculations use the same `.getElementsByClassName` method and according to the console, all of the table cells pertaining to the class names I specified (they're not important to this scenario) are retrieved without error.

Comment: The error implies that `itemQuantities[i]` is null or undefined. Try `console.log(itemQuantities[i])` to check

Comment: Could you post the rest of your code that is involved?

Comment: The `itemQuantities` array is indeed undefined.  I forgot to post the code that initializes the array, which I'll do momentarily.

Comment: It seems I was too quick to post that last comment.  The Javascript code DOES retrieve all of the input fields for the `itemQuantities` array, according to the console.

Comment: 99% of questions posted are required to have a [MCVE (**M**inimal, **C**omplete, and **V**erifiable **E**xample)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). 
Please post JavaScript/jQuery, CSS, and HTML that would be relevant to your question. Create a demo using any or all of the following services: 
[jsFiddle.net](https://jsfiddle.net/), 
[CodePen.io](https://codepen.io/),  
[Plunker.co](http://plnkr.co/), 
[JS Bin](https://jsbin.com/)
or a snippet (7th icon located on the text editor toolbar or CTRL+M).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `.value` attribute works.  I just wasn't properly checking to see if the input was empty.  The input in the quantity boxes is used to multiply various costs in order to determine certain aggregates.  I wound up using `isNaN()` to achieve the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

I just noted that you are indexing the variables with a "i" indexer, so if these lists doesn't have the same length, you are in trouble.

Just make sure that these lists are symmetrical and have the same length.

Comment: Every row in the table has one cell for each of the fields shown in my question, so the arrays are of uniform length.

Comment: @user3521737 - but are you sure? (did you check)

Comment: Yes, I've verified this.

Comment: ok, sometimes, when we have conditional rendering of the HTML, this uniformity may be lost...

Answer (score 0):

.val() and .attr() are jQuery methods. They don't exist in normal Javascript.

You get the elements with this:

```
var itemQuantities = document.getElementsByClassName("inputQty");
```

getElementsByClassName is a 'normal' javascript method. So you don't get jQuery additions to the elements by default.

try this way:

```
var itemQuantities = $('.inputQty');
```

then use the .val() and .attr() methods on them.

and instead of using index to iterate through the list you can do it like this:

```
itemQuantities.each(function(item) {
    ...
    doWhateverYouWantWithEach($(item));
    ...
});
```

or

```
itemQuantities.each(function() {
    ...
    doWhateverYouWantWithEachItem($(this));
    ...
});
```